# Angular Js cant get int with float form json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new to Angular js and i'm trying to sort by price (with float) a json file which contains prices as Strings. the problem is that it's sort the initial digit only - and not the whole number value, for example : 6.95 comes before   44.44 when sorting by high pricess ...  because it's 6 is greater than 4...

I've trying to create a function that returns

### parseInt(data[$scope.price])

but i don't know how to bind it to the model .

Thanks Roy.

```js
//----------------App.js file-------------------------------//

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [

  'ngRoute',
  'booksController'
]);


//create routes

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'views/books_list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
      })
      .when('/details/:itemId', { //add new page

        templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
        controller: 'DetailController'
      })
      .otherwise({

        redirectTo: '/list' // default view

      });

  }
]);

//------------------------------ Controller File ---------------------------------//
var booksController = angular.module("booksController", []);


// new module //productcontroler
var ListController = function($scope, $http) { // controller skech or blueprint

  $http.get('js/books.json').success(function(data) {

    $scope.books = data;
  });



};

var DetailController = function($scope, $http, $routeParams) { // new page controller

  //$routeParams Let us transter data between pages, once clicked on a product in first page - it will load form the $routeParams

  $http.get('js/books.json').success(function(data) {

    $scope.books = data;
    //should be  A parseInt(data[$scope.price]); function
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    //whichItem a scope property- a getter for the product id and transfer it to the new page
  });

};

booksController.controller("ListController", ListController); //bind module to controller
booksController.controller("DetailController", DetailController);
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav_logo">
    <h1>Book<span>Store</span></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" autofocus ng-model="query">
    <div class="select">
      <select ng-model="orderby">
        <option disabled selected value>-- Sort By --</option>
        <option value="author">Author</option>
        <option value="price">Price</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ascending">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" checked>Ascending</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" value="reverse">Descending</label>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="books_wrapper">

  <div class="books_box" ng-repeat="item in books | filter: query | orderBy: orderby:direction">
    <a href="#/details/{{books.indexOf(item)}}">
      <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
      <br/>
      <img src="img/{{item.pic}}.jpg" alt="{{item.pic}}">
      <p>
        <b>Author: </b>{{item.author}}
        <br/>
        <b>Genere: </b>{{item.genre}}
        <br/>
        <b>Price: {{item.price}} Nis </b>
        <br/>
        <br/>

      </p>
    </a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you should link directly your jsfiddle (and make it working). Than put the interesting slices of code directly into the question.

Comment: the link - http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/okv82xw3/

Comment: It is not working! (and it cannot: there is not `ng-app` inside)

Comment: sorry - i now edit the post with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do the integer/number parsing in the orderBy filter, by using the getter function definition.

Minimalist example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <select ng-model="orderby">
      <option value="author">Author</option>
      <option value="price">Price</option>
    </select>
    <div class="ascending">
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" checked>Ascending</label>
        &nbsp;
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="direction" name="direction" value="reverse">Descending</label>
    </div>
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="item in books | orderBy:mySortFn:direction">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.books = [
          {name: "Book A", price: "100.0"},
          {name: "Book B", price: "60.01"},
          {name: "Book C", price: "76.16"}
        ]

        $scope.orderby = "author"; // Initial Value

        $scope.mySortFn = function(item){
          return $scope.orderby === "price" ? parseFloat(item.price)
                                            : item[$scope.orderby];
        };
}]);
```

JS Bin: [Example Here](http://jsbin.com/susixonifa)

If you rather convert your model, from your jsfiddle, you can modify `$scope.books = data;` into something like below:

```
$scope.books = data.map(function(data){
    data.price = parseFloat(data.price); // or parseInt, whichever makes sense
    return data;
})
```

Comment: Kazenorin - Thanks for the quick answer, i'll check in a couple of hours - Good Day !

Comment: Kazenorin  - i'm using a separate module file which binds the controllers to the module ( i add a link to jsfiddle) so i cant bind the mySortFn function to a controller in a single page - like you did... any ideas?     http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/okv82xw3/1/

Comment: Still can't quite read or run your JSFiddle there, which controller corresponds to which part of the HTML? Can I assume `<nav>` block is controlled by ListController and the `<div class="books_wrapper">` block controlled by the DetailController, and that the two are siblings under the same parent and have two separate scope?

Comment: If the HTML you provided is all controlled by the `ListController` (i.e. if it's the `views/books_list.html` template), then you can simply add the getter function to the `ListController`. If this is the case, you may also want to check for `$scope.orderby`'s value in the getter function. (Update answer to reflect this)

Comment: kazenorin - thanks a whole lot - works, turns up i was really close to the solution but i used parseINT instead....THANKS!